# ASP.NET setting a javascript, jQuery setting from my code behind

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I would like to set a value:

```
    $('#swfupload').swfupload({
        upload_url: "uploadResume.aspx",
        file_post_name: 'uploadfile',
        post_params : {"session_guid" : [HERE]}
    });
```

...where [HERE] is the placeholder for my value, from my code behind in ASP.NET before the page is rendered.  I generate a guid, and I need that apart of the script on the page.  How can I accomplish this?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's a public or protected variable you can do

```
'<%= session_guid %>'
```

where `session_guid` is the name of your public or protected variable.

Comment: fixed the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

IF the script is IN the markup just use `<%= sessionGuid %>`, if the script is included then set a var in a preceeding script tag and reference it in the upload.